# How to extract a substring with all but initial two charactrers?

Tags: c, string

I want to extract a substring which has all the characters of the main string except the first two.
Like if some string has "0b1011", I need only "1011".
In the given code I need string c to have only "cdef" while it contains "cdefabcdef".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{   

    char a[6]="abcdef";
    char c[4];
    for(int i=2;i<6;i++)
        c[i-2]=a[i];
    printf("I need c: cdef\n");
    printf("I get c:%s",c);
    int k=strlen(c);
    printf("\nlength of c: %d\n",k );

}
```

Comment: What is your Question?

Comment: I also tried strncpy but that also didn't work.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. If you want to print `cdef`, just do `printf("%s", a+2);`.

Comment: @Kampi I want the string c to have only cdef but I am getting cdefabcdef.

Comment: What output do you get and what output do you expect? Please [edit] your question and make that clear _there_

Comment: `char c[4] `. can hold a string of maximum 3 characters. You need one more for the string NUL terminator. Read the chapter dealing with strings in your beginner's C textbook

Comment: @Blaze Actually I need to perform few more operations, so I need a string with all but initial two characters of main string.

Comment: Then do `char* myString = a+2;` and work with `myString`.

Comment: @NikhilShrivastava you should tell us what you're _actually_ trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your arrays are too small. They don't have room for the NUL-termination that is required in C

Try:

```
char a[7]="abcdef";  // Requires 6 characters and the NUL termination, i.e. 7
char c[5];
for(int i=2;i<7;i++)
{
    c[i-2]=a[i];
}
```

or

```
char a[7]="abcdef";  // Requires 6 characters and the NUL termination
char c[5];
strcpy(c, a+2);      // Adding 2 to a will skip the first two characters
```

Both of the above examples are a bit unsafe due to the hard coded array sizes. Here is a better alternative:

```
#define CHARS_TO_SKIP 2

char a[]="abcdef";                // a will automatically get the correct size, i.e. 7
char c[sizeof a - CHARS_TO_SKIP]; // c will automatically be CHARS_TO_SKIP smaller than a
strcpy(c, a + CHARS_TO_SKIP);
```

Comment: You should mention that the first snippet is still very poor, especially because of the hardcoded `7`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add an extra char at the end of the string to mark "end of string" with a special char '\0', when initializing the compiler does it automatically for you, but if you want to read the string char by char and copy it, you gotta access that last char and insert it to your second string to work fine, this is how the code looks like after fixing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


void main()
{

    const char a[7] = "abcdef";
    char c[5];
    for (int i = 2; i < 7; i++)
        c[i - 2] = a[i];

    printf("c:%s", c);
    int k = strlen(c);
    printf("\nlength of c: %d\n", k);

}
```

edit: by the way, your code is kinda bad and has a lot of hard parts but I just solved the problem the way you wanted it, and wouldn't recommend approaching the problem like that

Comment: You should mention that the "special char" is actually `0`